# Java core: returning null as boolean

Tags: java, null, boolean

I noticed this thing: my class has `boolean` member and at some run-point I see it's value in debugger as `null`. But when I use the getter method, it returns `false`.

I know, most books tell you that `boolean` in Java has only two values, unlike C/C++ in which every non-zero number can be interpreted as `true`. So I wonder, what's happening in there?

Are there any other situations when some value of other type or `null` can be interpreted as `false`? Perhaps explanation of this is somewhere in JLS, could someone point me to it?

**EDIT**: Indeed yesterday was a bad day for debugging. First i wasted 4 hours to find a source of a bug which disapeared when i reversed source and made same changes again. Then this. I just tried to reproduce and couldn't. Was it galucination or it's just monday is a hard day? I don't know. Thanks everyone for your responses! I guess you can vote to close or delete this question now.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a `Boolean` field?

Comment: Please show the code of this class. At least the field declaration and the getter method.

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your code? (boolean declaration, getter, the point where you see it null) And let us know what debugger you are using.

Comment: It is impossible. Show your code. I believe that somewhere you are using `Boolean` instead of `boolean`.

Comment: ok i will try to reproduce it in clean environment tomorrow and will post the code if it confirms

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like the field is declared as the [nullable, wrapper type `Boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) instead of a [`boolean` primitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: In this case, the getter would not return `false`, but throw a NPE.

Comment: @rolve unless it does something like `return boolField != null && boolField`

Comment: A getter will throw an NPE if it returns a `boolean`, but not if it returns a `Boolean`.

Comment: I think all we can really say is that we need to see the code first.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to reproduce outside the project tomorrow.

Comment: @AleksandrKravets can you verify that the field is a `Boolean`? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: @MattBall if it was Boolean I wouldn't ask =)

Comment: This answer is reasonable and i will accept it now regardless of it's usefulness for me.

Comment: @AleksandrKravets were you able to solve the problem? What was it?

Comment: @Matt Ball I wish I knew. It wasn't a problem since getter was returning false anyway. Why primitive boolean had null in expressions window - who knows, probably some kind of bug. It couldn't reproduce it yesterday. I should have made some screenshots. Maybe next time i will be smarter =)